# why does inline instance creation behave different?

Tags: javascript

Consider this code:

```
function Foo() {
}

Foo.prototype.alert = function() {
    alert(this);
}

(new Foo()).alert();
```

When executed (in jsfiddle), the alert shows that 'this' is the window object. Changing the last line to :

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.alert();
```

works as expected.

Why is the difference?

Comment: jsFiddle demo. Looks the the second `alert` doesn't get executed: http://jsfiddle.net/sf3M3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are missing a semi-colon:

```
function Foo() {
}

Foo.prototype.alert = function() {
    alert(this);
}; //Semi-colon here!

(new Foo()).alert();​
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ELUwF/1/) in which it appears to work as you expect.

What is actually happening is that the `alert` method gets called immediately, with a new instance of `Foo` passed into it, and `alert` is then called on the return value (which is `undefined`):

```
Foo.prototype.alert = function() {
    alert(this);
}(new Foo()).alert();
```

As @Nemoy has mentioned, if you just use `new Foo().alert()` you will get the expected behaviour because automatic semi-colon insertion will put a semi-colon in the right place for you (the lack of a semi-colon doesn't change the meaning of the code). And as the `new` operator has the highest precedence, the parentheses are not required.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is actually:

```
function Foo() {
}

Foo.prototype.alert = function() {
    alert(this);
}(new Foo()).alert();
```

Because of the missing semicolon, add a semicolon and it will run properly.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. This is one of the **many** reasons not to rely on the horror that is [automatic semicolon insertion](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9).